# Invalid Selector exception for image with selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

When Iam trying to click the element for this image, https://www.snapdeal.com/product/wonderchef-plastic-manual-chopper/675751798009 ,Iam getting invalid selector exception

```
@FindBy(xpath=//*[@id=\"content_wrapper\"]/section/div[4]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[10]/a/div[2]/img")
    
    private WebElement image;
    public WebElement getImage() {
    return image;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking this :

```
@FindBy(xpath=//*[@id=\"content_wrapper\"]/section/div[4]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[10]/a/div[2]/img")
```

we can see that, `\` and `\` are not allowed in `xpath` with **selenium-Java bindings.** Instead use this:

```
@FindBy(xpath=//*[@id ='content_wrapper']/section/div[4]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[10]/a/div[2]/img")
```

also, personally I would never use absolute xpath, instead I will try with relative xpath like this :

```
@FindBy(xpath= "//div[@class='zoomText']//following-sibling::div/descendant::img")
WebElement image;
```